# Getting ORA-01858 while running a query in sql transformation

Tags: oracle, date, informatica

I am getting Getting ORA-01858 (a non numeric character was found where a numeric was expected) while running a query in sql transformation in informatica.

I am using TO_DATE function in my query like.

```
TO_DATE('31/DEC/9999','DD/MON/YYYY')
NVL(PROFIT,TO_DATE('31/DEC/9999','DD/MON/YYYY')
TO_DATE(A.SELL_DATE,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS') >= TO_DATE('01/JAN/22','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')
TO_DATE(A.SELL_DATE,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS') <= TO_DATE('18/APR/22','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')
TO_DATE(A.BUY_DATE,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS') = TO_DATE('18/APR/22','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Can anyone help me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Is this code you are sharing, multiple lines? I'm having a hard time parsing it.

Comment: Are `a.buy_date` and `a.sell_date` dates already?  If so, you wouldn't want to call `to_date` on them.

Comment: You're using `MM` for several dates where you should be using `MON`. On 19c Oracle handles that mistake gracefully, but you may want to fix it.

Comment: Why do you try to fit `APR` in the `MM` date format element? Please, check the documentation: [Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A)

Comment: Is Profit a string or a numeric? If it's numeric, Oracle could be expecting both items in `nvl` to be the same type.

Comment: pls use `TO_DATE('01/JAN/22','DD/MON/YYYY')` to convert.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestion's I'll try to implement the changes and will share the result.